# reading a file using read -r is behaving really weird with MINGW

Tags: bash, mingw

I have the following snippet which works fine in the terminal app in ubuntu but the same code behaves weirdly in MINGW (a shell which git bash uses in windows).

```
while true;
do
    while IFS=, read -r x owner login_name
    do
       echo "$x $owner $login_name" # putting this makes it work on MINGW
        getVisitors "$x" "$owner" "$login_name"
    done<"${machines}"
done

function join_by { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

function getVisitors
{
    machine="$1"
    team="$2"
    user="$3"
    echo "Running ${cmd} on ${machine}"


        result=$(ssh -q -i "${key_file}" -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t ${user}@${machine} ${cmd})
        isMachineUp=$?
        ips=()
        for visitor in ${result}
        do
            shopt -s nocasematch
            if [[ ! "$visitor" =~ $myHostName.* ]];then
                ips+=("${visitor}")
            fi
            shopt -u nocasematch
        done
        if [[ $isMachineUp -ne 0 ]];then
            ips=("-");
        else
            if [[ $ips == "" ]];then
                ips="-";
            fi
        fi
        echo "Users found on $machine === > $ips"
        addMachine $(join_by , "${ips}") "${machine}" "${team}"
}
```

The above code should keep looping forever and parse the "${machines}" file line by line which is a csv file like the one given below.

`foo,-,admin
 bar,-,admin
 dor,-,admin`

However, the code snippet just parses the first line in `MINGW` shell environment.

Comment: how did you confirmed that `the code snippet just parses the first line in MINGW shell environment` ? have you tried changing `getVisitors` to `echo` ? what is `getVisitors` doing ?

Comment: I did put a echo statement above this method call and it just keeps printing the first line of the csv file in the mingw environment.